# What is Rumble?

Tags: foiled

There is a setting on options called "rumble". When I turned it off I noticed no difference in gameplay. What is the point of this option?

Comment: I'm guessing that option is for the rumble feature on many game pads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rumble typically has to do with vibration in the game controller.

There will be no effect on gameplay itself, just the feedback that makes the controller vibrate.

If you are not using a controller to play your game, there will be no noticeable changes.